# Referencing bucket name as variable to a resource in s3 event in serverless.yml

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, lambda, serverless

I have the following configuration in serverless.yml functioning well:

```
service: fx-crawler-av
frameworkVersion: '2'

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: python3.8
  lambdaHashingVersion: 20201221
  region: eu-west-1

  environment:
    S3BucketName: !Ref 'S3BucketFXDataStorage'
    AlphaVantageAPIKey: ${ssm:AlphaVantageAPIKey}

package:
  exclude:
    - requirements.txt
    - package.json
    - package-lock.json
    - node_modules/**
    - .serverless/**
    - .env/**

functions:
  fetch_api:
    handler: handler.fetch_api
    iamRoleStatements:
      - Effect: "Allow"        
        Action:
          - "s3:PutObject"
        Resource:
          Fn::Join:
            - ""
            - - "arn:aws:s3:::"
              - "Ref": "S3BucketFXDataStorage"
              - "/*"
  set_ccy_pair_scope:
    handler: handler.set_ccy_pair_scope
    iamRoleStatements:
      - Effect: "Allow"        
        Action:
          - "s3:GetObject"
        Resource:
          Fn::Join:
            - ""
            - - "arn:aws:s3:::"
              - "Ref": "S3BucketFXDataStorage"
              - "/*"
      - Effect: "Allow"        
        Action:
          - "s3:ListBucket"
        Resource:
          Fn::Join:
            - ""
            - - "arn:aws:s3:::"
              - "Ref": "S3BucketFXDataStorage"
  get_ccy_list:
    handler: handler.get_ccy_list
    iamRoleStatements:
      - Effect: "Allow"        
        Action:
          - "s3:GetObject"
        Resource:
          Fn::Join:
            - ""
            - - "arn:aws:s3:::"
              - "Ref": "S3BucketFXDataStorage"
              - "/*"
  append_parquet_file:
    handler: handler.append_parquet_file
    iamRoleStatements:
      - Effect: "Allow"        
        Action:
          - "s3:GetObject"
          - "s3:PutObject"
        Resource:
          Fn::Join:
            - ""
            - - "arn:aws:s3:::"
              - "Ref": "S3BucketFXDataStorage"
              - "/*"
      - Effect: "Allow"        
        Action:
          - "s3:ListBucket"
        Resource:
          Fn::Join:
            - ""
            - - "arn:aws:s3:::"
              - "Ref": "S3BucketFXDataStorage"

resources:
  Resources:
    S3BucketFXDataStorage:
      Type: 'AWS::S3::Bucket'
      Properties:
        BucketName: !Join
          - ''
          - - !Ref 'AWS::AccountId'
            - '-fx-data-storage'

stepFunctions:
  stateMachines:
    FXCrawler:
      events:
        - schedule: cron(35 21 * * ? *)
      definition:
        Comment: "State machine for crawling AlphaVantage API for FX rates"
        StartAt: GetCurrencyList
        States:
          GetCurrencyList:
            Type: Task
            Resource: 
              Fn::GetAtt: [get_ccy_list, Arn]
            Next: SetCurrencyPairScope
          SetCurrencyPairScope:
            Type: Task
            Resource:
              Fn::GetAtt: [set_ccy_pair_scope, Arn]
            Next: mapped_task
          mapped_task:
            Type: Map
            ItemsPath: '$.ccy_pair_scope'
            MaxConcurrency: 1
            Iterator:
              StartAt: FetchAPI
              States:
                FetchAPI:
                  Type: Task
                  Resource:
                    Fn::GetAtt: [fetch_api, Arn]
                  Next: WaitForAPI
                WaitForAPI:
                  Type: Wait
                  Seconds: 60
                  End: true
            End: true

plugins:
  - serverless-python-requirements
  - serverless-iam-roles-per-function
  - serverless-step-functions

custom:
  pythonRequirements:
    slim: true
    dockerizePip: true
    useDownloadCache: true
```

Now I would like to add an S3 event trigger to my `append_parquet_file` function, e.g.:

```
  append_parquet_file:
    handler: handler.append_parquet_file
    events:
      - s3:
          bucket: !Ref 'S3BucketFXDataStorage'
          event: s3:ObjectCreated:*
          rules:
            - suffix: .json
```

But unfortunately this does not seem to work..

1. I get a warning during deployment `Serverless: Configuration warning at 'functions.append_parquet_file.events[0].s3.bucket': should be string`
2. The deployment fails:

```
Serverless Error ---------------------------------------
 
  [object Object] - Bucket name must conform to pattern (?!^(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}$)(^(([a-z0-9]|[a-z0-9][a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])\.)*([a-z0-9]|[a-z0-9][a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])$). Please check provider.s3.[object Object] and/or s3 events of function "append_parquet_file".
```

I tried multiple ways to create and inject the bucket name as variable but did not succeed. Any idea what can go wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to create bucket resouces, according to the docs, you can specify the bucket and add properties you need and bucket will create and configure automatically to setup the trigger

```js
functions:
  resize:
    handler: resize.handler
    events:
      - s3: bucketOne
 
provider:
  s3:
    bucketOne:
      name: my-custom-bucket-name
      # Eventual additional properties in camel case
```

https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/s3#custom-bucket-configuration

Answer (score 0):

You should [reference](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/variables/) your bucket as follows:

```
bucket: ${self:resources.Resources.S3BucketFXDataStorage.Properties.BucketName}
```

Comment: Thanks Marcin, but I get the identical errors for this approach, too.

Comment: @ati Is this part of the same template? Can you provide complete, reproducible code demonstrating the issue?

Comment: included upper my full serverless.yml file as-is

Answer (score 0):

All you need is this: (remove the double quotes)

```
    Resource: !Ref S3BucketFXDataStorage
    event: s3:ObjectCreated:*
    existing: true
```

and you have another problem in the policies, try this instead to reference you bucket in the policies:

```
Resource: !Join ["", [!GetAtt S3BucketFXDataStorage.Arn, "/*" ]]
```